# Looking for deleted files on Photos

Tags: photos

I deleted photos and then looked for them under Photos, File, Show Recently Deleted, but the message says "no recently deleted." Where are the deleted files??  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many photos you deleted and the age of your Mac, it may take a moment or two to populate the list.  In the meantime, the dialog does show "No Recently Deleted".

Also, photos auto delete after 30 days so keep that in mind. (In your original post, you don't specify when you deleted the photos.)
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I just checked Photos about 24 hours after deleting a bunch of photos and it still says "No Recently Deleted."  Very strange!  I haven't checked yet to see if my photos were actually deleted from Photos.